# Java Swing components

Tags: java, arrays, swing

How can I create a 7 JCheckBox components from this array and add it to a JPanel

```
String toppings[]={"Mushrooms","Onions","Cheese","Green Peppers","Pepperoni","Black Olives","Sausage"};
```

Comment: See [How to use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox)
and [How to Use Panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Comment: What have you tried? Voting to close as 'too broads', and down voting for apparent lack of effort.

Comment: You'll always want to show us your attempt with your question. Else we end up regurgitating text from a tutorial that already exists.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson it is an application which includes `JRadioButton` , `JList` and many more `swing` components but I was stuck on the `JCheckBox` part. I put up the whole code earlier in a different question and the guys told me to narrow it down to the specific problem and this is exactly what I have done. Now you want the whole code again?

Comment: *"I put up the whole code earlier in a different question and the guys told me to narrow it down to the specific problem"* Post an *[mcve]* that actually shows your attempt to *achieve* the stated goal. After you've made an [edit] to the question to add an MCVE, let me know. I might remove the down vote (& close vote) and even add an up vote.

Comment: Guys here are unbelievable down voting when I put up the whole code of what I have done claiming they want the specific problem and then down voting again when I put up the specific problem claiming they want to see the whole code of my effort/what I have done.

Comment: @JavaCid With all due respect, this is not an uncommon problem, which has already been asked dozens of times before, it's also not the most complicated of issues, sure from your perspective, it's earth stopping, but if you don't understand the basic flow control concepts, if you have bigger issues to be worried about.  SO is not a tutorial site and 99% of you question can be answered in two simple tutorials, so before you start getting upset at the people who are volunteering to help you, have some consideration of how/what you're asking - as some friendly advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate on the `String` array with a `for` statement. 
In the `for` create a `CheckBox` instance for each `String` and add it in the `JPanel` :

```
String toppings[]={"Mushrooms","Onions","Cheese","Green Peppers","Pepperoni","Black Olives","Sausage"};
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
for (String topping : toppings){
    panel.add(new JCheckBox(topping));
}
```